# How to display PDF file in browser

Tags: java, servlets

In my servlet I am using the code below to open a PDF file in a browser, but instead, it shows a download dialog box.

What I am doing wrong?

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
out = response.getWriter();
String filepath = "D:/MyFolder/PDF/MyFile.pdf";

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + filepath + ";");
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:/MyFolder/PDF/MyFile.pdf");

fileOut.close();
out.close();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html?

Comment: I have one solution but not much fessible i.e use apache poi api and convert each page in pdf file into image and then display it

Comment: How can i do it in servlet??

Comment: It depends on the browser and the installed plug-ins, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can try to do the same with

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+filepath+";");
```

Answer (score 7):

As you have to set the response type with the following configuration:-

```
File outPutFile=new File(generatedFile);
stream = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
response.setContentLength((int) outPutFile.length());
```

Comment: minor typo: outPut -> output (it is only 1 word)

Comment: @SaviNuclear I tried it but its not working can you suggest some other method ???

Comment: @vineethPrabhakaran could you please give the error message or log details to understand you problem.

Answer (score 2):

you need this:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf") 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename= .. " )
```

Otherwise, the browser will prompt you to open/save. ( if content type is octet-stream, or content-disposition is attachment )

if you want the pdf to be displayed in a tab, you need to set target = "_blank" in the html ( or angular, jsp, whatever framework you are using ).

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.coderanch.com/t/561315/Servlets/java/display-pdf-file-broswer)  is related

Is your browser Firefox? [This](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959670) might be relevant

Comment: Actually i tried using it  but still i am not able show the pdf