# Unable to use view PDF in java

Tags: java, user-interface, websphere

I am trying to view PDF using but I am getting the following error:
java.awt.HeadlessException

When I try It on local it works and the code is the following :

```
             
        
              String filePath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\name.pdf";

                // build a controller
                SwingController controller = new SwingController();

                // Build a SwingViewFactory configured with the controller
                SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller);

                // Use the factory to build a JPanel that is pre-configured
                //with a complete, active Viewer UI.
                JPanel viewerComponentPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();

                // add copy keyboard command
                ComponentKeyBinding.install(controller, viewerComponentPanel);

                // add interactive mouse link annotation support via callback
                controller.getDocumentViewController().setAnnotationCallback(
                      new org.icepdf.ri.common.MyAnnotationCallback(
                             controller.getDocumentViewController()));

                // Create a JFrame to display the panel in
                JFrame window = new JFrame("Using the Viewer Component");
                window.getContentPane().add(viewerComponentPanel);
                window.pack();
                window.setVisible(true);

                // Open a PDF document to view
                controller.openDocument(filePath);
```

but when i compile and install the war file on web sphere i get the above error .
Note that WebSphere is installed on linux VM

Comment: is your WebSphere box a server with no gui?

Comment: The Linux installation WebSphere runs on, is probably not using a graphical user interface and therefore running a "headless" JVM. See https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/headless.html

Comment: I access websphere   through 192.168.xx.xx so it should have gui

Comment: The fact that it's got a LAN ip address is not relevant

Comment: So why on earth would you want to display PDFs on the servers display, if you are not even sure it has X11 and all the stuff installed (where you usually dont want that on a server...)?

Comment: How to install non headless JVM

Comment: When the user click on the document I need to allow to view the pdf instead of downloading it I am using jsf framework

Comment: You need to avoid asking XY questions and instead [state your goal](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions)

Comment: Then you need to convert it 'to html'

Comment: How to convert it where the pdf is located on the server and i need to retrieve it first then after click show it

Comment: It might be easier to get the browser to display it [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476706/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-browser)

Comment: Easier ... and you will probably get a more accurate rendering of the original PDF.